# How to format the output of query in SQLcl to have no header?

Tags: oracle-sqlcl

I want to execute a query that will produce an output that are SQL commands too to be executed later. Something like:

```
SELECT
    'DROP ' || OBJECT_TYPE || ' "' || owner || '"."' || object_name || '";' as command
FROM
    ALL_OBJECTS;
```

The problem is that the output always have the header. In this case "command".
I tried the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/sql-developer-command-line/21.2/sqcug/working-sqlcl.html), but its very simple and brief in its explanations.

How can I disable the header, or where can I find a more complete documentation on how the formatting in SQLcl works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET HEADING OFF
```

Very difficult to guess what the [72 system variables](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/sql-developer-command-line/21.2/sqcug/working-sqlcl.html#GUID-5B365E3E-B4A8-45CA-A13B-CD41F5FCC156) of the SQLcl environment do.